# error loading package inside foreach when using testthat

Tags: r, unit-testing, foreach, testthat

I am trying to a debug an issue with using unit tests with testthat.  The code runs fine if run manually, however it seems when running `test()`, the workers inside the foreach don't seem to have access to the package or functions inside the package I am testing.  The code is quite complex so I don't have a great working example, but here is the outline of the structure:

unit test in tests/testthat:

```
test_that("dataset runs successful", {
  expect_snapshot_output(myFunc(dataset, params))
})
```

MyFunc calls another func, and inside that func, creates workers to run some code:

```
final_out <- foreach(i = 1:nrow(data), 
    .combine = c, 
    .export = c("func1", "func2", "params"),
    .packages = c("fields", "dplyr")) %dopar% {
    output = func1(stuff)
    more = func2(stuff)
    out = rbind(output, more)
    return (out)
}
```

The workers don't seem to have access to `func1`, `func2` etc..

I tried adding the name of the package to packages in this line, but it doesn't work either.

Any ideas?
As I mentioned, this is only an issue when trying to run the unit tests and I suspect it is somehow related to how the package I am testing is being loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the workers are started they do not have the full set of packages a normal session has; pass all package names of the packages in the search path when the tests are running in the the local session to the `.packages` argument.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that might be the issue, but when I tried passing the name of the package I am testing (it is a package we developed), it says package not found.  Func1, Func2 etc are part of that package.  I also tried adapting the code inside to specify such as: `MyPackage::Func1` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using multiple libraries? It may be that the worker session is not picking up the alternative library? You could try setting a hard coded library path in the function to see if this solves it.

Comment: The package that doesn't seem to be loading is the package I developed that I am trying to do the unit tests on.  I don't know where the library path for this is created when devtools::test() runs that would then be available to the workers?

Comment: Actually I think it was an issue with the global env loading various things.. with a clean env, after adding the package name to the .packages, things work!